# Syncing button with option element

Tags: javascript, html

```
     function displayPage() {
 var sel = document.getElementById("subject");
    switch ( sel ){
            case 'Math':
          document.getElementById("butt").onclick="location.href='kk.html'";
            break;
    }
}

    <select id="subject" class="c4"><br />
 <option value="math">Math</option>
  <option value="science">Science</option>
  <option value="physics">Physics</option>
  <option value="programming">Programming</option>
</select>
        <button class="button" onclick="displayPage()" id="butt">Submit</button>
```

Well I want to sync the option element with a button so if user selected math it goes to p1.html, science goes to p2.html, etc...I believe the switch expression is incorrect how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use value of select element

```
var sel = document.getElementById("subject");
var val = sel[sel.selectedIndex].value
```

then use `val` in your switch
or you can use `text` if you want to compare, but remember JS is case sensitive.